# Merge two sorted arrays without using additional memory

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays, in-place

We have two sorted arrays of integers. 
Without using additional memory we need to merge these two arrays such that the smallest numbers are in the 1st array and the remaining numbers are in the second array.

For instance, if your two arrays are $A=[1,3,9,14]$ and $B=[2,4,15]$, the result should be $A=[1,2,3,4], B=[9,14,15]$. Entries are integers, and you can use only $O(1)$ extra memory for auxiliary variables.

Comment: Just to clarify, if your two arrays are $A=[1,3,9,14]$ and $B=[2,4,15]$, should the result be $A=[1,2,3,4], B=[9,14,15]$? Also, are the entries integers? Can you use an auxiliary variable for swapping?

Comment: Yes, The values are integers. You can use with only with constant memory.

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049). As the commentary indicates, the details are a bit hairy.

Comment: [Very closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/worst-case-on-ln-n-in-place-stable-sort). Community, is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Raphael I have tried to create a virtual array with length that equal to the array1's length + array2's length then merge the virtual array with regular QuickSort, But this solution feel very cumbersome.

Comment: How does your "virtual" array (what is that?) not take up space in $\omega(1)$? Why would you want to sort, especially seeing that merge is possible in linear time?

Comment: Please clarify if the two resulting arrays have to be sorted, and which running times are permissible.

Comment: The virtual array is just a warper for the  2 sorted arrays, with length that equal to the array1's length + array2's length. when the quick sort algorithm (or any other algorithm that sort array without using additional memory) try to get or set from specific index the virtual array know to routing to the real index. for example, A=[1,3,9,14] and B=[2,4,15], The virtual array is array with length 7 the first element (the element in the index 0) is 1, the last element (the element in the index 6) is 15, the element in the index 4 is 2 and so one.

Comment: Now we have a unsorted array with 7 items without using additional memory and we can sort him with NLogN time. N = m+k, m is the length A and k is the length of B. @Raphael does that make sense?

Comment: @GuyKahlon Yes. I suspect that you should have linear running time in total, though. Please check the original problem statement.

Answer (score -2):

Here, great solution, from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays-o1-extra-space/

Below is C++ implementation of above algorithm.

```
// C++ program for implementation of Sieve of Atkin
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Merge ar1[] and ar2[] with O(1) extra space
void merge(int ar1[], int ar2[], int m, int n)
{
    // Iterate through all elements of ar2[] starting from
    // the last element
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        /* Find the smallest element greater than ar2[i]. Move all
           elements one position ahead till the smallest greater
           element is not found */
        int j, last = ar1[m-1];
        for (j=m-1; j >= 0 && ar1[j] > ar2[i]; j--)
            ar1[j+1] = ar1[j];

        // If there was a greater element
        if (j != m-1)
        {
            ar1[j+1] = ar2[i];
            ar2[i] = last;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not a good fit for this site. What are the ideas? Why does it work? Code should be pseudocode at most.

Comment: @Raphael actually you right I'll update my answer, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also while this solution uses O(1) memory, it takes O(n^2) time, which is quite bad for merging. For instance if you use your merge procedure inside of merge sort algorithm you'll end up with O(n^2) time complexity instead of O(n*log(n)) if you stick with extra memory "vanilla" variant